# Adobe Analytics doesn't generate my report

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, adobe-analytics

I'm trying to send some data when a certain event happens, from the backend, through a POST request (using DataInsertation api) to Analytics data collection servers.

I implemented the following POST request:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(myUrl);
        request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.Method = "POST";

        var xmlString = "";
        using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter())
        {
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(myXmlClass.GetType());
            serializer.Serialize(stringWriter, myXmlClass);
            xmlString = stringWriter.ToString();
        }

        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xmlString);
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

        Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        dataStream.Close();

        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

        dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        reader.Close();
        dataStream.Close();
        response.Close();
```

The url and report suite id are provided by AdobeClientCare and the reponse returns a 200 success code. Then I went to https://my.omniture.com/login/ and search for my reports. Here is where I got lost, I am not sure where to look or what to look.

I am also considering the option that the data wasn't actually collected, even the request returned OK.

I've read a bunch of links and the documentation, I am stil confused about how these reports are generated. Any help/explanation is welcomed.

Edit: I'm using XmlSerializer to build my xml body for the request

```
[Serializeble]
[XmlRoot ("Request")]
Public class MyXml ()
{
    public PageName {get;set;}
    public ReportSuiteId {get;set}
    public VisitorId {get;set;}
    public Events {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Hi Nick, the magic in the data insertion is not in the http request but in the xml payload you are posting. Can add details about the xml you are sending and the url you are sending to?

Comment: Hi Chris de Groot,thanks for your help. unfortunately I'm not at work and I don't know by heart the url, but it was something like something/b/ss//6 and I received 2 report suite ids for dev and qa env, so somethinhg/b/ss/myId/6. I edited the post with my xml class.

Comment: Hi Nick,I have found that the documentation is pretty accurate for the Data Insertion feature. I suggest you start with curl and a static XML document and see that work, them implement in high level code. I'm happy to look at your XML and URL if you like. Also note the naming  in use here. https://marketing.adobe.com/developer/documentation/data-insertion/r-sample-http-post C.

Comment: I already went through Data Insertion documentation 2 times, but I still don't know why my report is not generated into Analytics. I'm using Fiddler to look at my POST request and it's matching the samples provided in the documentation. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Please, let me know your thoughts on this. Thanks Chris de Groot!